# How to run feature file of using subprocess.run in pytest framework?

Tags: python

Trying to execute feature file of pytest project from different pytest project using `subprocess.run`

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
from os import path

# parent_folder=path.join(str(path(__file__).parent.parent))
fodler_path = path.join(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent), "so2c-integration-test-framework")
subprocess.run(args="behave ./features/Demo/test_requisition.feature", cwd=fodler_path)
#subprocess.run(args="ls", cwd=fodler_path)
print("done running")
```

error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'behave ./features/Demo/test_requisition.feature'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) as default uses `shell=False` - and it needs list

```
args=["behave", "./features/Demo/test_requisition.feature"]
```

Or you have to use `shell=True` to use string `args="...commnad..."`

```
subprocess.run(...., shell=True)
```

---

```
subprocess.run(args="behave ./features/Demo/test_requisition.feature", 
               cwd=fodler_path, shell=True)

subprocess.run(args=["behave", "./features/Demo/test_requisition.feature"], 
               cwd=fodler_path)
```

Comment: if this solves your problem then mark my answer as accepted.